# Recognize Tiled Internet Layers

Tags: arcobjects, openstreetmap, tiles

Is there a way to recognize a Tiled Internet Layer using arcobjects in .NET?
I've tryed several ways but I always end up in a dead road...

```
ILayerFile lyrf = new LayerFile();
lyrf.Open(@"G:\mypath.lyr");
ILayer layer = lyrf.Layer;

MapServerLayer msl = layer as MapServerLayer;

ITiledMapServer tms = msl as ITiledMapServer;
```

I'm stuck obtaining the `MapServerLayer`: layer doesn't answer to `ITiledMapServer` nor to `IMapServerLayer`. 
Is there another way to obtain it?